# External linkage and »extern "C"« block

Tags: c++, c

I have an `int ID`, which I want to define in C++ and make available for C linkage (contrived case for the sake of simplicity):

```
/* i.h */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
        extern int ID;
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Here's a C and a C++ program using the `int`:

```
/* m.cpp */
#include "i.h"
#include <iostream>
int main() { std::cout << ID << std::endl; }

/* m.c */
#include "i.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { printf("%d\n", ID); }
```

Now what I'm wondering is the syntax of `extern "C"` and/or `extern`. Here's how `int ID` can and cannot be defined:

```
/* i.cpp */
//                     const int ID = 88;   // no C linkage, obviously, LNK2019/1120
// extern "C"          const int ID = 88;   // provides C linkage
// extern "C" {        const int ID = 88; } // no C linkage, surprisingly, LNK2019/1120
// extern "C" { extern const int ID = 88; } // C linkage restored
```

Compiling:

```
cl /nologo /W4 m.cpp i.cpp /MD /EHsc
cl /nologo /W4 m.c   i.cpp /MD
```

What I don't understand is the syntax when `extern "C"` is used with a `{block}`. I have to repeat the `extern`, whereas with the blockless form of `extern "C"` I do not. Is this just a syntax quirk or is there more to it?

I stumbled upon this issue on page 98 of *Inside COM* by Dale Rogerson. There is a code listing with the nested `extern` and a comment intended to clarify (but which I don't understand):

```
#include <objbase.h>
extern "C"{
  extern const IID IID_IX = {0x32bb8320, 0x41b, 0x11cf, ...};
  // The extern is required to allocate memory for C++ constants.
}
```

Can anyone explain the internal `extern`?

Comment: Looking at the example at page 98, I do believe that the linker will iteratively resolve linkage. IID_IX will internally have the C++ linkage, however, on the outside they will be visible with the C linkage.

Comment: This is an example of the "let's reuse a keyword with a vaguely related meaning" method of language design.

Answer (score 5):

The inner `extern` means what expected: "the symbol is defined somewhere else, it has *external linkage*, don't allocate space for it in this unit (unless defined here as well)".

The outer `extern "C" { ... }` has maybe a bit misleading syntax, it only tells the compiler "if you are creating names of any symbols with *external linkage* inside this block, use traditional C naming (*C language linkage*) instead of C++ name mangling (*C++ language linkage*) for them". But it does not specify that all things inside the block are "defined somewhere else" (have *external linkage*) -- they are still declared with the default *internal linkage*. That's why you need the inner `extern` as well.

The one-line variant `extern "C" <variable declaration>` is just a shorthand, as you probably want to define an external variable if you care about its cross-unit symbol name.

(As a side-note, I would include `i.h` also in `i.cpp`, that way I wouldn't have to remember to mess with `extern "C"` any more in the implementation.)

Answer (score 3):

> Here's how int ID can and cannot be defined:

Careful! `extern "C"` has different effects in different contexts.

N3797 §7.5/7:

> A declaration directly contained in a *linkage-specification* is **treated
>   as if it contains the `extern` specifier (7.1.1) for the purpose of
>   determining the linkage of the declared name and whether it is a
>   definition**. Such a declaration shall not specify a storage class.
>
> ```
> extern "C" int i; // declaration
> extern "C" {
>     int i;           // definition
> }
> ```

So the second line in your snippet is just a declaration whilst your third line is also a definition. This changes what effect the *linkage-specification* has on the declarations - you can't give a name defined in a C++ translation unit C linkage. You have to make it a pure declaration.

Comment: You're saying the second line in my snippet is just a declaration, but the way MSVC (Version 18.00.30501 für x86) compiles it, the init value (`88`) is printed on the screen, which seems to contradict the notion that it is a mere declaration, at least as far as MSVC is concerned.

Comment: Please speak English.

Comment: @BoltClock please restore his comment and mine, I don't like such high-handed edits.

Comment: I don't see the point in doing so when nobody but those who can speak German can understand them anyway (and if the comments are meant for just the two of you, then they're highly distracting to everyone else). Posts and comments should be in English whether you like it or not, no exceptions.

Comment: I seriously doubt that your intervention has improved anything, BoltClock - but nvm.
As i said, VC++ assuredly has its own rules regarding linkage, and therefore you should ask in their forums (or read the manual).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `const` and `extern` are warring with each other.  `const` means (among other things), "Make this definition internal, unless there's an explicit `extern` on it.".  When the definition is in an `extern "C"` block, there's no `extern` *directly* on the definition, so the "implicit internal" from the `const` takes precedence.  The other definitions all have an `extern` directly on the definition, so it becomes external.